# Can anyone send e-mails to an email account at an OpenNIC domain?

Tags: email, dns

[OpenNIC](http://www.opennicproject.org) offers domains like .fur and .dyn. It seems you can't access those domains unless you point them to DNS resolutions, which is bad because if you have a site.dyn people will not be able to access it normally.

My question is if people would be able to send you e-mails to your yourself@site.dyn and vice-versa without any configuration.

Comment: Do you have MX records pointing to .dyn domain?

Comment: Not yet, was considering if worth having a .dyn domain, since as I commented the domains can't be accessed by people without configuration, but if people could e-mail normally to .dyn domains at least for e-mails it sounds good to me. But I couldn't find this information in their site or faqs so I asked here. I'm aware that I would need to have MX set up, my doubt is whether that'd be enough.

Comment: You'll need to configure your MX records and A Host records at whomever you bought the domain from.  It's pretty self explanatory once you login to the account.

Answer (score 0):

No; people using non-OpenNIC DNS will not be able to send you anything, because their servers will not be able to resolve the domain.

The best you can do is to force your friends to use this DNS, and then exchange emails with them.